# How is it possible to remove the chapter name from the header, and add page numbering to all pages?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, chapters, page-numbering

By default each page has the name of the chapter and the page number in the header. Except for the first pages of the chapters, where the page number is in the footer, centered.

I tried to get rid of it using this command, but it does not work as expected:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\empty}
```

I would like to make the headers empty, and display the page number aligned rigth in the footer on each page.

Comment: Share what have you done so far. MWE?

Comment: How to do it exactly can depend on your document class and loaded packages, so please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing where you have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option I frequently use is the **fancyhdr** package.
With this you can change many configurations in the headers, providing you change your pagestyle to *fancy*. A minimum working example would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %No Horizontal Line at top
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\chapter{Testchapter}
\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

If the page number should be right aligned on each page even if the document is twosided:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\refoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```